# Unix/Linux/MacOSX online training

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, command-line-interface

I am a web dev seeking deep knowledge of the Unix-style command line.

Please if anyone has a recommendation on any high quality courses avail. over the web respond to this thread.

Comment: You probably want to pick a platform/distro; they each have quirks specific to the platform. FreeBSD is different from OS X is different from each of the Linux distros for certain tasks while being similar enough to confuse you.

Comment: Second, I'd highly recommend you install a VM (VMWare Player, Virtualbox) and install a sandbox of the platform of choice in which to play around and learn. Makes it handy and convenient to roll back to a previous state using snapshots.

Comment: As for online courses, I don't know any (which is why I didn't submit an answer), because personally the best way I've found to learn is a combination of playing with systems/VM's to create an actual server or workstation to use and looking for a couple good books for reference material at the local bookstore or Amazon.

Comment: +1 @Bart... You'll learn a lot more actually using it rather than just reading about it, and VMWare is invaluable for helping with that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bart, you should be a little more specific and select a distro.  A good source for various online trainings in linux, be it beginner to expert is

```
http://education-portal.com/articles/10_Sites_Offering_Free_Linux_Courses_Online.html
```

I use VMWare to install different platforms and I agree that it is the best way, being hands-on, to learn.

TrainSignal.com has great training, although not free.  I have used it for various Windows products while simultaneous working on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a generic introduction to commonly-used tools (and how to pipe them together for awesome hackery), I highly recommend the [Linux Phrasebook by Scott Granneman.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328380)  It teaches individual useful commands and shows you how to build off of each to cover very common everyday tasks, making life easier.  The book is 'pocket-sized' and only a couple hundred pages, but there's a lot of good info.  Each topic/solution is at most a couple pages.

It is a book and not an online resource, but I personally have found it invaluable.